# Who decides to publish different versions of the same textbook?

Tags: books

Do authors or publishers decide to publish too similar versions of  textbooks that feel like cash grabs? Or do the publishers suggest it? Three examples — 1.  [James Stewart's](https://redd.it/9bovt6) pricey first year *Calculus* books.

2. Ross, Westerfield, Jaffe, and Jordan wrote at least four textbooks titled *Corporate Finance*. I know the first one is the longest. But the last three feel like duplicates.

> *Corporate Finance*
> [2019 12th Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/corporate-finance-ross-westerfield/M9781259918940.html)

> *Corporate Finance: Core Principles and
> Applications*
> [2021 Sixth Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/corporate-finance-core-principles-applications-ross-westerfield/M9781260013894.html)

> *Essentials of Corporate Finance* [2020 Tenth Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/essentials-corporate-finance-ross-westerfield/M9781260013955.html)

> *Fundamentals of Corporate Finance*
> [2019 12th Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/fundamentals-corporate-finance-ross-westerfield/M9781259918957.html)

3. Brealey, Myers, and Allen wrote at least three textbooks titled *Corporate Finance*. The first one is the longest. But the last two feel like duplicates.

> *Principles of Corporate Finance*
> [2020 13th Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/principles-corporate-finance-brealey-myers/M9781260013900.html)

> *Principles of Corporate Finance,
> Concise Edition* [2011 2nd Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/principles-corporate-finance-concise-brealey-myers/M9780073530741.html)

> *Fundamentals of Corporate Finance*
> [2020 Tenth Edition](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/fundamentals-corporate-finance-brealey-myers/M9781260013962.html)

Comment: I do not know the topic, but new textbooks in my field usually update content, include new material and sometimes modernize presentation. I cannot follow why OP uses the derogatory or polemic term "cash grab by the author", writing is a textbook is a lot of work and the author honorarium really not that impressive for the amount of work involved. One could certainly earn more with consultancy or just working in the industry. It may be a business for the publisher, but the OP specifically asks about the author. Not voting to close, but downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as "who suggests a new edition, the author or the publisher?"

The answer is "it depends". Either can suggest. A lot will depend on how long it's been since the previous edition, and whether there's anything new to write about. If the new edition does go ahead you can be sure that both author & publisher approve of it, and that (the publisher at least) think they can sell copies of the new edition. There's usually a summary in each new edition detailing what's new.

As for "duplicate" textbooks: remember, you don't have to buy it if you feel there's no value.